# Bazel Watcher not Terminating Node Process (Error: Listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000)

Tags: node.js, docker, bazel, docker-image

I have a Bazel BUILD file with a `nodejs_image`:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")
ts_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(
        include = ["**/*.ts"],
        exclude = ["**/*.spec.ts"]
    ),
    deps = [
        "//packages/enums/src:lib",
        "//packages/hello/src:lib",
        "@npm//faker",
        "@npm//@types/faker",
        "@npm//express",
        "@npm//@types/express",
        "@npm//cors",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    data = [":lib"],
    entry_point = ":index.ts",
)
```

which boots up a simple Express Node.Js server:

```js
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000'));
```

When I run

```
ibazel run //services/server/src:server
```

the server starts just fine. But when I change some code and the Bazel Watcher restarts, I get this error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

Hence, the previous Node.Js process wasn't killed and the port is still in use.

- Do I have to handle the termination inside my Node.Js application?
- Or is there some other method to run Node.Js code with Bazel Watcher?
- Or is it an issue with the Bazel Watcher?

You can try it yourself: https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo/tree/f23b960b57a94abbb5cbc13853b3e8ec4a1997ab

Comment: Yeah something about how rules_docker starts docker images dosen't work well, I wouldn't suggest using nodesjs_image for dev, use nodejs_binary instead.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Is it possible to run multiple `nodejs_binary`'s at once?

Comment: Yeah we use https://github.com/atlassian/bazel-tools/tree/master/multirun to run mutiple under the same bazel / ibazel command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Toxicable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4083539/toxicable) has stated, I've changed `nodejs_image` to `nodejs_binary` like this:

```
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "nodejs_binary")
nodejs_binary(
    name = "server",
    data = [":lib"],
    entry_point = ":index.ts",
)
```

Which fixed the issue.